# Congratulations to all new MVPS and Thanks for all who contribute to the success of this community

Tags: discussion, mvp, recognition

I want to take a moment to thank Salesforce and all contributors and moderators of this community. It's just pleasing to see some of the contributors of this community making to the new  MVP [list](https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2016/07/salesforce-mvps-summer-2016.html) and a lot of folks got renewed. Nice work everyone and let's keep helping each other and learn together.

Comment: For anyone thinking of becoming an MVP @bob_buzzard has a piece about it on Medium https://medium.com/@bob_buzzard/the-mvp-life-a28502b27778#.i4cz5bwph

Comment: I know one thing, this community is truly amazing and the key to bring me upto where I'm today in salesforce world. Not to offend, but the reality is SFSE is the first visit for a technical issue, not the salesforce developer forum. Congratulations all the MVPs!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Thank you Mohith. Were it not for SF.SE, I can assure you that my name would not have been on that list today. I feel both honored and humbled to be named as a Salesforce MVPs. I've learned a great deal about Salesforce and coding since having first logged into this site looking for help several years ago.

Many of those who helped me were and still are MVPs. I've learned so much from far too many to list all their names. Some in that group are almost like "heroes" to me in that they constantly inspire me and have given me cause to return here. I'm constantly learning from what's posted and it feeds my thirst for knowledge as well as for comradery.

This a great place. There's nothing quite like it and I'm proud to be a part of Salesforce.StackExchange.

Comment: Congratulations and truly deserved it :) .I have been inspired by your work and dedication and thanks for all you do to help folks here .Cheers !!!

Comment: Yah I agree It's good to see some of SE members in MVP list :)

Comment: Congratulations and you truly deserved it :) and Thanks for all your help to me and community.

Comment: Congratulations!!!!

Comment: Glad to see you in the program mate :)

Comment: Congrats. You are Legend to us as well.

Answer (score 27):

The SFSE community has been amazing. I've been proud to be a part of the SFSE family for quiet some time now and I'm happy to report that I've have joined the MVP ranks in this Summer'16 nomination cycle along with Cal. I totally agree - it's been a great learning process on SFSE and I hope in the process I've made some meaningful contributions of my own.

Though I'm also active on Forums, am a DUG leader and I've been speaking at Dreamforce for a number of years, I take a lot of pride in seeing myself as a SFSE member being nominated as a MVP.

At the same time, I strongly believe we still have some really good members who deserve to be MVPs and I'm confident that they'll be joining the ohana in the coming cycles/ years. Thank you for the support and let's keep up the amazing work on SFSE so far!

Comment: Congratulations and you truly deserved it :) and Thanks for all your help to me and community.

Comment: Congratulations!!!!

Comment: Agreed! There are many great contributors here that I'm confident will become future MVPs should they continue to remain active and are also involved in other community as well. The DallasDeveloperGroup is an important part of my life as is the work we do with nonprofits! Congrats my friend!

Comment: Overdue and well deserved!

Comment: Hurray to Gaurav!!

Answer (score 15):

Thanks for being such an awesome contributor Mohith! When I first proposed this site I had an inkling that it'd do well, but I was never expecting the growth we've actually seen in the last four years.

It's a tribute to the community as a whole that so many people are willing to share their expertise and time with others.

Comment: Parker Haris got excited about this community during MVP Lightning event and most of CTO I have met have thanked all community members for all the awesome stuff they do to help and thrive .Also I am pleased to see SFDC Engineers stepping and helping folks with lightning related queries .All this feels truly awesome and kudos to you for proposing and seeing the future .Lets gather for a breakfast during dreamforce .One thing i am disappointed is we are not given slots to speak about awesomeness of this site and how it can help us :(. Nevertheless thank you all

Comment: I remember telling Parker about the site while it was in beta at Dreamforce one year, not sure he ever signed up though :)